# Heatmap in Openlayers using an XML (KML formatted) string, styling is incorrect

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am currently attempting to create a Heatmap in OpenLayers using a KML string. From this string, I read the features, add them into a VectorSource, then add the source to the Heatmap layer. Unfortunately, when I add the Heatmap layer to the map, the data is displayed with pin icons. In the example documentation on the OpenLayers site, found at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html?q=earthq, the Heatmap has blended circles which is exactly how I want mine to look. Here is the code that I use to create the layer.

```
       var kmlFeatures = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(data["xml"],{
            dataProjection : 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection : 'EPSG:3857'
          });

        var source = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: kmlFeatures,
            format: new ol.format.KML({
                extractStyles: false
              })
        })

        for (var i = 0; i < source.getFeatures().length; i++) {
            var feature = source.getFeatures()[i];
            var name = feature.get('name');
            feature.set('weight', parseInt(name));
            feature.set('type', "OTHER");
        }

        var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
            source: source,
            blur: parseInt(15, 10),
            radius: parseInt(5, 10)
          });

        map.getMap().addLayer(vector);
```

I know that the input data, data["xml"] to be exact, is being displayed correctly because I see all of the various features being displayed on the map. The styling is just simply incorrect. Here is a picture of what is being displayed on my screen.

What I am seeing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m15y.jpg

What I would like to see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxqf6.jpg

Thank you for any help I can get!

Comment: From http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.layer.Heatmap.html "Weight values should range from 0 to 1 (and values outside will be clamped to that range)" In the example all the data is in the range 5 to 5.9 and 5 is subtracted before displaying it. Since you are using parseInt your data is presumably integer and the weight settings will need to be divided by the largest possible value to produce values in the range 0 to 1. But I don't think that explains the icons, presumably they have been imported from the KML and if they continue to appear they will need to be stripped out by your code.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I believe the weights are normalized to be between 0 and 1; however, regarding the icons, I do not have any styling in the KML file. I was reading the KML docs and this is what I found. "A Placemark is one of the most commonly used features in Google Earth. It marks a position on the Earth's surface, using a yellow pushpin as the icon". So I believe the pushpin is coming from the default KML styling. But this still does not explain why my features are not taking on the styling of what the Heatmap should be providing right?

Comment: If "name" already contains values between 0 and 1 using parseInt will always return weight 0 and nothing will be displayed.  You should use parseFloat instead.

Comment: If there are styles included the features they could override the layer style.  Adding `feature.setStyle(undefined);` to the `for` loop should remove them.

Comment: @Mike I appreciate the suggestions truly, I will try them out and see what I find.

Comment: @Mike Thank you so much, setting the style to undefined in the for loop worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mike, the solution was to set the feature styles to undefined. This ensures the pins do not override the styles that are being applied from the Heatmap layer.

So the new code looks as follows:

```
        var kmlFeatures = new ol.format.KML().readFeatures(data["xml"],{
            dataProjection : 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection : 'EPSG:3857'
          });

        var source = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: kmlFeatures,
            format: new ol.format.KML({
                extractStyles: false
            })
        })

        for (var i = 0; i < source.getFeatures().length; i++) {
            var feature = source.getFeatures()[i];
            var name = feature.get('name');
            feature.set('weight', parseFloat(name));
            feature.set('type', "OTHER");
            feature.setStyle(undefined);
        }

        var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
            source: source,
            blur: parseInt(15, 10),
            radius: parseInt(5, 10)
          });

        map.getMap().addLayer(vector);
```

The solution feels a bit hacky, but it works.